# Loading python string with 'u' as json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, unicode

I have a string in the following strings

```
json_string = '{u"favorited": false, u"contributors": null}'
json_string1 = '{"favorited": false, "contributors": null}'
```

The following json load works fine.

```
json.loads(json_string1 )
```

But, the following json load give me value error, how to fix this?

```
json.loads(json_string)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Comment: `u` prefixed string in not part of JSON specs. Why do you want `json.loads` to accept it (or what is your *real* problem) ?

Comment: I got these type of strings by type casting a dictionary which represented a json to string `str(json_dict)`.

Comment: What version of Python you use? If this is Python3.x it won't work for you since in Python3.x there are no such thing like `unicode` anymore.

Comment: @PatNowak,  maybe you wanted to say that all text is Unicode in python 3.x :) It's a completely different thing

Comment: Don't do this: `str(json_dict)`.  If you have a Python dictionary, use `json.dumps` to convert it to a string.

Comment: how do you get **`null`** and **`false`** there then, `str(...)` should result in `None` and `False`. And that is no JavaScript Object Notation, but just Python.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `json.dumps` to convert a Python dictionary to a string, not `str`.  Then you can expect `json.loads` to work:

Incorrect:

```
>>> D = {u"favorited": False, u"contributors": None}
>>> s = str(D)
>>> s
"{u'favorited': False, u'contributors': None}"
>>> json.loads(s)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\json\__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 364, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
  File "D:\dev\Python27\lib\json\decoder.py", line 380, in raw_decode
    obj, end = self.scan_once(s, idx)
ValueError: Expecting property name: line 1 column 2 (char 1)
```

Correct:

```
>>> D = {u"favorited": False, u"contributors": None}
>>> s = json.dumps(D)
>>> s
'{"favorited": false, "contributors": null}'
>>> json.loads(s)
{u'favorited': False, u'contributors': None}
```

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same problem with strings I received from a customer. The strings arrived with u's. I found a workaround using the ast package:

```
import ast
import json

my_str='{u"favorited": false, u"contributors": null}'
my_str=my_str.replace('"',"'")
my_str=my_str.replace(': false',': False')
my_str=my_str.replace(': null',': None')
my_str = ast.literal_eval(my_str)
my_dumps=json.dumps(my_str)
my_json=json.loads(my_dumps)
```

Note the replacement of "false" and "null" by "False" and "None", since the literal_eval only recognizes specific types of Python literal structures. This means that if you may need more replacements in your code - depending on the strings you receive.

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the `u` suffix from the string using REGEX and then load the JSON

```
s = '{u"favorited": false, u"contributors": null}'
json_string = re.sub('(\W)\s*u"',r'\1"', s)
json.loads(json_string )
```